# JavaScript find property match with in formcontrol object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

Hi I've an array of object which I'm looping

```
let DOArr: [] =[]

{
    "selectedDC": {
        "DC": [{
                "id": "23293839",
                "name": "Legal · L5",
                "active": true,
                "parentid": "23293827",
                "level": 4
            },
            {
                "id": "23293839",
                "name": "Balance · L2",
                "active": true,
                "parentid": "23293807",
                "level": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}

 for (const tmpDataOwner of this.dataConceptDetailsObj['selectedDC']['DC']) {
        this.DOArr.push(tmpDataOwner.id)
 }
```

Now I've so already populated checkbox formcontrols which I've selected default value as false.
I want to make those checkbox formcontrol true/checked whose `id` and `name` matches the above

```
 const formControls = this.dataOwnerList.map(
          (control) => {
            if(this.DOArr.includes(control.id)){
              return new FormControl(true);
            }
            else{
              return new FormControl(false);
            }
          }
        );
```

Now I'm only checking for id but I also want to check for name basically need strong checking for both `id` & `name`

Comment: Heads up, the code in the first example will not compile as-is; the property bag has not been given a name. Additionally, `dataOwnerList` is also undefined. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I propose dropping the `for` in favor of mapping `dataConceptDetailsObj` directly into `DOArr` since it's less work. Then instead of pushing the `id` on its lonesome, return a property bag with `id` and `name` keys whose values correspond to the current item.

```js
let dataConceptDetailsObj = {
    "selectedDC": {
        "DC": [{
            "id": "23293839",
            "name": "Legal · L5",
            "active": true,
            "parentid": "23293827",
            "level": 4
        }, {
            "id": "23293839",
            "name": "Balance · L2",
            "active": true,
            "parentid": "23293807",
            "level": 2
        }]
    }
}

let DOArr = dataConceptDetailsObj['selectedDC']['DC']
    .map((item) => {
        return {
            id: item.id,
            name: item.name
        }
    })
```

And for the second part:

Use the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method of the DOArr array instead of `includes`. Thus allowing you to check both the id and name.

> The find() method returns the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned. -MDN

```js
const formControls = this.dataOwnerList.map(
    (control) => {
        let item = this.DOArr.find(
            (i) => i.id == control.id && i.name == control.name
        );
        return new FormControl((item !== undefined));
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Jed, but one query I'm setting selectAll: new FormControl(false), to false initially when I preselect checkboxes and if checked count is 1 & total values are also same, selectAll checkbox is not selected